# Replacing specific ranges of values with NaNs of a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I want to replace a range of values for multiple columns with NaNs based off range value conditions on that specific column.

Ie: Suppose I had `[col1_min = 5, col1_max = 15]`, and `[col2_min = 2, col2_max = 20]` and the columns looked like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,50,15,10,4], 'col2':[12,10,100,11,56]})

col1   col2
1      12
50     10
15     100
10     11
4      56
```

The desired output would be:

```
df_filtered

col1   col2
nan    12
nan    10
15     nan
10     11
4      nan
```

Pseudo code I could do is `groupby` each column within the boundary using 'df.groupby('col1' or 'col2')' and then filter each column then merge back into the original but I'd like to keep memory cost to the minimum.

Is there any way to do this easily?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Series.where`:

```
df['col1']=df['col1'].where(df['col1'].between(5,15))
df['col2']=df['col2'].where(df['col2'].between(2,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do it by

```
condition = {'col1':[5,15],'col2':[2,20]}
pd.concat([df.loc[df[x].between(*y),x]for x, y  in condition.items()],axis=1)
Out[313]: 
   col1  col2
0   NaN  12.0
1   NaN  10.0
2  15.0   NaN
3  10.0  11.0
```